# Secure a method, Fatal error, __construct() must implement interface

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm very new to Symfony so, I'm very sorry if I ask a newbie question, but got a production service running, and all falling now, so trying to hot fix the problem.

I was in need to add a security for a specific part of the code, and to do so

I added

```
if (true === $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
```

in my code by following doc provided here : https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/securing_services.html

My whole code looks like something like :

```
<?php

namespace SUP\SupervisorBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
...

class AutoCompleteController extends Controller
{
    protected $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }
```

But for unknown reason, I got an `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to SUP\SupervisorBundle\Controller\AutoCompleteController::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface, none given, called in sup/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 186 and defined`

I really don't understand what goes wrong, any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: Maybe show the implementation `AuthorizationCheckerInterface`???

Comment: Why down voted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the way to achieve this was to *not* add

```
protected $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }
```

and instead of

```
$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

I did use

```
$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

Comment: You are making this too hard.  You are already extending the base controller so $this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're not injecting an instance of AuthorizationCheckerInterface.

Are you using autowiring? How are your services defined? Did you try retrieving the service from the container instead of injecting it (although injection would be the way to go)? http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container.html